# How to save the switch cases results in different columns

Tags: sql

I have the following query currently:

```
SELECT  name, id, 
  CASE 
    WHEN( status = 'Missing' AND severity = 'Optional' ) AND ( id=123 ) 
    THEN COALESCE(count(patchid),0)
    ELSE 0
  END AS missingoptional,

  CASE 
    WHEN( status = 'Missing' AND severity = 'Important' ) AND ( id=123 ) 
    THEN COALESCE(count(patchid),0)
    ELSE 0
  END  as missingimportant

FROM tablename
GROUP BY  name, id, status, severity
ORDER BY id
```

Current result:

```
name            id          missingoptional     missingimportant
abc             123         10                  0
abc             123         0                   20
```

Expected result:

```
name            id          missingoptional     missingimportant
abc             123         10                  20
```

Please let me know what changes do I have to do in the above query to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT name, id, 
  SUM(CASE 
      WHEN( status = 'Missing' AND severity = 'Optional' ) AND ( id=123 ) 
          THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END) AS missingoptional,
  SUM(CASE 
      WHEN( status = 'Missing' AND severity = 'Important' ) AND ( id=123 ) 
          THEN 1
      ELSE 0
      END) as missingimportant
    FROM tablename
GROUP BY name, id
ORDER BY id
```

I removed status and severity from the `GROUP BY`, and instead put `SUM()` in the select-list to do aggregation.

Comment: I get the following error:
`Invalid operation: aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function;`

Comment: count inside the "SUM" was the issue.

Comment: This one is the closest answer. @jarlh Please  update your answer with the following change so that i can mark it as right answer:
Instead of `COALESCE(count(patchid),0)` write `1`

Answer (score 0):

Use MAX() aggregate function

```
SELECT  name, id, 
  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN( status = 'Missing' AND severity = 'Optional' ) AND ( id=123 ) 
    THEN COALESCE(count(patchid),0)
    ELSE 0
  END) AS missingoptional,

  MAX(CASE 
    WHEN( status = 'Missing' AND severity = 'Important' ) AND ( id=123 ) 
    THEN COALESCE(count(patchid),0)
    ELSE 0
  END)  as missingimportant

FROM tablename
GROUP BY  name, id
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Still GROUP BY status and severity?

Comment: I get `Invalid operation: aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function;`